# Iterator in loop is considered a series form?

Tags: pine-script

There seems to be a bug in pine script that has broken an indicator I wrote. Previously (before ~Oct2020),  I had an indicator that did some calculation inside a for loop using the ema function.  Now, Pine Script throws an error when I try and add my script:

> Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 21: Cannot call 'ema' with
> arguments (series[float], series[integer]); available overloads:
> ema(series[float], integer) => series[float]

Here's a  sample of what I'm trying to run:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
emastep = 5
emashort = 5
thisema = 0.0
emanum = 10
lastema = ema(close, emashort)
for i = 1 to emanum
    thisema := ema(close, round(i*emastep))
plot(thisema)
```

The issue seems to be the "i" in the `ema(close, round(i*emastep))` part.  What's interesting is a sample script from the pine script manual (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#for-statement) also throws the same error now.  The following sample from the above link doesn't work:

```
//@version=4
study("RMA in for loop")
sum = 0.0
for i = 1 to 2
    sum := sum + rma(close, i)
plot(sum)
```

Any thoughts on how to get around this?  i in a for loop shouldn't be a series form, right?

Answer (score 2):

The bug that threw the error is, as I suspected, related to the `i` iterator in the `for` loop.  If I create my own iterator, and use that, everything works ok.  This is my solution I came up with:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
emastep = 5
emashort = 5
thisema = 0.0
emanum = 10
lastema = ema(close, emashort)
iter = 1
for i = 1 to emanum
    thisema := ema(close, round(iter*emastep))
    iter := iter + 1 
plot(thisema)
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Nice solution! I'm surprised that works, because your iter variable is also a mutable variable. Good find :) I've upvoted your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Several pine functions support [dynamic length arguments](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-functions-support-dynamic-length-arguments-20554/).
However, `rma()` is not one of them.

This function has never accepted a dynamic argument length, also not in v3 of Pine.
Just because it doesn't throw an error in v3 doesn't mean the calculation is correct.
This example calculates the `rma` in v3, once in a loop and once with a fixed value, but both should result in an `rma(close, 15)`.

```
//@version=3
study("RMA fixed length vs variable length")

sum = 0.0
i = 0

for i = 1 to 15
    sum := rma(close, i)

plot(rma(close, 15), color=green)
plot(sum, color=red)
```

Both should return the `rma` with a length of 15, but the results are very different (=incorrect), because of the use of the unsupported variable length input.

[image: rma variable vs fixed length]

The reference manual for [rma()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_rma) shows an example of how to calculate `rma` in a function.
You can use that in your code as a workaround.

```
//@version=4
study("RMA in for loop")

// Built-in RMA
plot(rma(close, 15), color=color.green)

// The same on pine
pine_rma(src, length) =>
    alpha = 1/length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : alpha * src + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

plot(pine_rma(close, 15), color=color.red)


// Your code with built-in rma(), this will NOT work
// sum = 0.0
// for i = 1 to 2
//     sum := sum + rma(close, i)

// plot(sum, color.blue)


// Your code with pine_rma(), this will work
sum = 0.0
for i = 1 to 2
    sum := sum + pine_rma(close, i)

plot(sum, color.blue)
```

Notice how the red and the green line in this code are identical (overlapping).
This proves that the result of `pine_rma()` is identical to the built-in `rma()`, but with the extra advantage of accepting mutable variables as input, which results in the blue line, as you intended.

[image: Working]

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I guess something changed though because the `i` iterator in the loop shouldn't be dynamic, but static.  I actually came up with a work around, detailed below.